# Wildfly does not call own LoginModule

Tags: wildfly, securitydomain

i have migrated an application from glassfish to wildfly 9.0.0CR2. And i have a problem with my own ServerAuthModule and LoginModule. In the standalone-full.xml i have configured this:

```
            <security-domain name="CustomSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication-jaspi>
                    <login-module-stack name="Custom">
                        <login-module code="logic.security.realm.module.CustomLoginModule" flag="required" module="deployment.logic.security.realm.jar"/>
                    </login-module-stack>
                    <auth-module code="logic.security.realm.sam.CustomServerAuthenticationModule" flag="required" login-module-stack-ref="Custom" module="deployment.logic.security.realm.jar"/>
                </authentication-jaspi>
            </security-domain>
```

When i call my webapplication i am getting the below log :

```
javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX00070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:286)
    at org.jboss.as.security.RealmDirectLoginModule.login(RealmDirectLoginModule.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at logic.security.realm.context.RequestAuthContext.authenticate(RequestAuthContext.java:78)
    at logic.security.realm.sam.mechanism.HostSignOn.authenticate(HostSignOn.java:77)
    at logic.security.realm.sam.CustomServerAuthenticationModule.doAuthenticate(CustomServerAuthenticationModule.java:238)
    at logic.security.realm.sam.CustomServerAuthenticationModule.validateRequest(CustomServerAuthenticationModule.java:380)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.message.config.JBossServerAuthContext.invokeModules(JBossServerAuthContext.java:157)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.message.config.JBossServerAuthContext.validateRequest(JBossServerAuthContext.java:135)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JASPIServerAuthenticationManager.isValid(JASPIServerAuthenticationManager.java:115)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jaspi.JASPIAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(JASPIAuthenticationMechanism.java:115)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:339)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:325)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:138)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:113)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:106)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:253)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Wildfly does not call my LoginModule, he is calling one of his own. I don't find any mistakes in my configurations and my classes implements only the interface LoginModule and ServerAuthModule. Has anybody the same issue?

**EDIT**:
i solved my issue, in my ServerAuthModule i have realm ="custom.realm" and so i have to change the name of the login module stack from "Custom" to "custom.realm"

Comment: Could you answer your own question since you solved the issue?

Comment: The javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext needs the name of the login-module-stack. This name was in my ServerAuthModule default "custom.realm" but it has to match the login-module-stack so I renamed it. Otherwise the LoginContext does not call the CustomLoginModule